# Vue prop is object. Change detection doesn't work

Tags: javascript, oop, vue.js

I would like to ask for explanation of the following situation.

I have an object, that contains other objects inside. I pass this object to a vue component as a prop.

```
classs parent {

     constructor () {
        this.child = new Child();
     }

}
```

Then, I change an attribute of the child object. However, the following vue code doesn't do anything and seems like the watch method is not even called.

```
    watch : {
        property : {
            handler (newVal) {
                console.log('property updated');
            },
            deep: true
        }

    },
```

Because the vue prop is actually a reference to the Parent object, it is changed. Now, how do I detect changes of the Parent, if Child changes?

Comment: *I change an attribute of the child object.* How?

Comment: Asking, then not responding.

Comment: Sorry guys. parent.child.property = 1;.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This works fine *if* the data item you are changing existed before it became Vue data. In other words, the only items that are reactive are the ones Vue knew about when it built the instance.

[Vue cannot detect property addition](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#Change-Detection-Caveats). If you want to add a child or a member of a child, you will need to use [`$set`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#vm-set) or make your change happen by assigning to an already-reactive element.

```js
class Child {
  constructor() {
    this.a = 'one';
  }
}

class Parent {
  constructor() {
    this.child = new Child();
  }
}

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    p: new Parent()
  },
  watch: {
    p: {
      handler(newVal) {
        console.log('property updated', newVal);
      },
      deep: true
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.p.child.a = 'two';
    }, 500);
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.$set(this.p.child, 'b', 'something completely new');
    }, 2500);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@latest/dist/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">

</div>
```

Comment: I think, this is what I needed. Thank you!

Comment: When "this" is not associated with Vue, you can directly import Vue. In that case, you can access $set via "Vue.set()".

Answer (score 1):

Change detection on objects and arrays can only work on a **reference change** basis.

Do `parent.prop="whatever"`, then `parent = {...parent}` which changes the reference and makes Vue pick up the change.

> https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#Change-Detection-Caveats